# Menu list goes out of screen when anyDensity="false"

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I'm looking for a solution of the next problem.

When I set in my Manifest file `android:anyDensity="false"` in  tag - Menu list that drops down when I click on Menu in Action Bar goes out of the screen and within screen there is only a half of menu item is shown. F.i. if i have "Settings" menu item there only "Sett" will be shown.

This is the screen:

[image]

Can anybody help me?
My andriod 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

the Only answer that i found so far is to change the location of your view in the layout so it can find space to show :(